# Does TypeORM incorrectly infer return type when findOne function has specific "select" input?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, typescript-generics, nestjs-typeorm

[image]
Here, the `Quiz` entity has `@ManyToOne (decorator)` relation to `Author` entity.
The `Author` entity has many properties like `id`, `name`, `age`, not just `id`.

If I do not pass the `select` option in the input of `findOne` function, then the `Quiz` type (It's a class, and also a type) is correct as return type.

But, if I pass the `select` option, it means the returned quiz object will have limited author object, it will not have full author object, right? So, the return type cannot be exactly `Quiz` type, right?

I can manually create the correct return type like this:

```js
type TQuizWithAuthorJustId = {
  [Key in keyof Quiz]: Key extends 'author' ? Pick<Author, 'id'> : Quiz[Key];
};
```

and I can manually assign this correct return type, but is it the only way? Does TypeORM really fails to automatically determine correct return type?

I tried searching for this issue in TypeORM docs, but I could not find anything.